# Using at all in a positive sentence that is not a conditional

Tags: polarity-items

I've done a quick-search regarding this problem and found this interesting [discussion](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/301648/110852). The sentence is:

> This dangerous message has two parts. The first is that ‘learning’ can
> be ‘delivered’ **at all** – in other words that ‘learning’ is equivalent
> to the course or to materials which can be used for learning.

As I could see there, I couldn't find any negative sense, or a conditional sense. So, why the author use **at all**?

Oh, also if you are interested in knowing the whole context, here's the [link](https://donaldhtaylor.wordpress.com/writing/whats-in-a-word/). This link was shared in a C2 English group, I'm thinking the probability of the writer might have mistakenly written that is lesser.

Perhaps, by rephrasing the sentence containing **at all** will make me understand easily.

Comment: I'd say that "at all" is negatively-oriented in that the expectation is that learning can't be delivered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clue is in an earlier paragraph:

> Nobody delivers learning. Learning is something that happens inside the mind of an individual. It simply cannot be delivered.

He is saying that the teacher delivers *teaching*, but *learning* is something that the students have to do for themselves. So, learning *cannot* be delivered 'at all'.